# Is there a PHP namespace shortcut for this?

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to find a way to mass apply these namespaces, as this would be inconvenient to write out. I know I can simply do, use `jream\ as j`  but I would like to see if it's possible to avoid the backslash.

```
require '../jream/Autoload.php';

use jream\Autoload as Autoload,
    jream\Database as Database,
    jream\Exception as Exception,
    jream\Form as Form,
    jream\Hash as Hash,
    jream\Output as Output,
    jream\Registry as Registry,
    jream\Session as Session;

new Autoload('../jream');
```

Isn't there a way to say something along these lines: `jream\\* as *;` ?

Any tips would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the very least you can skip all the redundant `as` aliasing:

```
use jream\Autoload,
    jream\Database,
    jream\Exception,
    jream\Form,
    jream\Hash,
    jream\Output,
    jream\Registry,
    jream\Session;
```

If you want to use everything in the namespace without typing it out one by one, then indeed the only real choice is to alias the namespace as a whole and use a backslash:

```
use jream as j;

new j\Autoload;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

> Isn't there a way to say something along these lines: jream\* as *; ?

No, but you can do this:

```
// use-jream.php
class Autoload extends jream\Autoload {}
class Database extends jream\Database {}
...

// index.php
require_once 'use-jream.php'

new Autoload('../jream');
```

But I wouldn't really recommend doing it.

And of course, if you want to just change the default namespace:

```
namespace jream;

new Autoload('../jream');
```

That is all an `import jream.*` could ever mean in PHP, since PHP has absolutely no way to determine if a class could possibly exist in a certain namespace unless you inform it.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I like the last part about setting a namespace!